# PHP: unable to login using fetch_row

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am following phpacademy tutorials. Following is the code to login but this is not working. Please help me to get it fixed

**login.php**

```
$login= login($username, $password);
        if($login===FALSE){
            $errors[]='Username/Password is not correct';
        }
        else{
            echo 'Welcome Back!';
        }
```

**users.php**

```
function user_id_from_username($username){
        global $connect;
        $username=sanitize($connect,$username);
        $query= "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'";
        $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if(!$result){
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
        }
        return mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    }

    function login($username, $password){
        global $connect;
        $user_id= user_id_from_username($username);

        $username= sanitize($connect, $username);
        $password= md5($password);

        $query= "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= '{$username}' and password='{$password}'";

        $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if(!$result){
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
        }
        return (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)?$user_id:FALSE;


    }
```

This code always results  `Username/ Password is not correct` . Can someone please help me whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Besides wondering why you're querying the database twice, and why you're using MySQLi but still interpolating values into the query rather than prepared statements/bind variables, and why you're using md5() as a hashing algorithm for a password?

Comment: If it's a valid login, you're returning $user_id (`return (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)?$user_id:FALSE;`), but testing against Boolean using strict-typed comparison (`if($login===FALSE){`)

Comment: sir as i mentioned in my question that i m following phpacademy lecutres they are bit older ,  i just want to  improve my techniques they use

Comment: Improve your techniques with the methods I mentioned above.... that still doesn't explain why you're querying the database twice

Answer (score 3):

This phpacademy tutorial is just awful, written by some incompetent noob. **Querying database twice is alone enough to tell that**, not to mention other faults. You should quit it immediately and find yourself some *reliable* source.

here goes your function, but written using **PDO**, not mysqli. As you're not writing a production code, but just learning, an API change wouldn't make a big deal for you, yet PDO is way simpler than mysqli when used properly. By learning PDO prepared statements you indeed will improve your skills, instead of ruining them by means of aforementioned "tutorial". Thus, move to PDO.

```
function login($username, $password){
    global $connect;
    $query = "SELECT user_id, password FROM users WHERE username=?";
    $stmt  = $connect->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$username]);
    if ($row = $stmt->fetch() && $row['password'] == md5($password)) {
        return $row['user_id'];
    }
}
```

note that you should change md5()for [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), changing registration code accordingly.

Comment: Just one note for someone who comes later ,phpacademy is   not done by  'incompetent noob', it was me who is following  lectures recorded 4 years back, They have complete series about  PDO as well ,actually i was planning to go for it after this one ,